# properly display float with printf in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, floating-point, 32-bit, gnu-assembler

this program meant to add 2 float nums and display their respective results but program gives unwanted results and i dont understand why is it necessary to allocate 16 bytes for a float rather as a double occupies 8 bytes so why not allocate only 8 bytes for float?

```
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    subl    $12,    %esp    # allocate enough memory for a floating point value
    flds    (V0)        # load loading single precision variable 1
    flds    (V1)        # load single precision variable 2
    fadd    %st(1), %st(0)      # add both of them [ NOTE: reg ST(0) contains correct result ]
    fstpl   (%esp)      # store the float
    pushl   $.LC0
    call    printf
    addl    $16,    %esp    # return allocated mem to OS [ 12 + 4 = 16 ]
    ret

.LC0:   .string "%f\n"

V0: .float 9.3
V1: .float 9.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks buggy to me; ESP is 16-byte aligned *before* the call to `main` (which pushes a 4-byte return address), so it should be using `sub $12, %esp` to recreate 16-byte alignment as required by the i386 System V ABI (assuming you're on Linux) before the call to `printf`.

That's what you'd see if you compiled a C function with a C compiler.

I'd also recommend using `flds` for the single-precision loads and `fstpl` for the double-precision store, to make the sizes explicit.  This is also buggy; the default is the same for load and store, and this program needs float load and double store.  (The default is single-precision `float`, dword)

(`printf "%f"` takes a `double` because there's no way of passing a `float` in C to a variadic function: the default promotions apply.)

Comment: peter sir please correct my program a bit and please give me something to learn about this 16 byte alignment

Comment: @Qureshi: As I said in my answer, you'd get similar but working code from a C compiler like `gcc -O1`.   https://godbolt.org/ is a handy way to look at asm output.  Or make the changes described by my answer.  Re: alignment: [Why does System V / AMD64 ABI mandate a 16 byte stack alignment?](//stackoverflow.com/q/49391001) and [gcc x86-32 stack alignment and calling printf](//stackoverflow.com/q/52287214).  Also [Stack alignment on x86](//stackoverflow.com/q/21748272)

Comment: @Qureshi: Oh wait, your code has other bugs.  `call pr_float` pushes are return address between the `double` and the format-string pointer.  Don't do that, just call printf from main.

Comment: yeah i forget about main address is pushed on stack when calling any other function that why this happend thanks man u really helped me

Comment: tell me more about loading single precision and storing double precision. see the updated code above